# Arcgis javascript - Set different symbol for each graphic in feature layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-js-api

I have a feature layer that contains 12 items with the same defined style. But I want to change each item to have a unique symbol when rendered.

```js
var Layer = new FeatureLayer("http://...my map server.../0");

Layer.graphics.forEach(function (entry) {
    // loop through each item
    console.log(entry);                        
    console.log(entry.attributes.FID);

    var symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({ "url":"/images/icons/fid_" + entry.attributes.FID + ".png", "height":20, "width":20 });  
    entry.setSymbol(symbol);
    var renderer = new esri.renderer.SimpleRenderer(symbol);  
    Layer.setRenderer(renderer); // <-- this appears to override all previous items
});

map.addLayer(Layer);
```

I omitted some code to keep this simple; what I have now sets a symbol, but it's the symbol of the last `entry` that is looped for all items.

I need each `entry` to have a unique symbol defined by its `FID` (0-11)

I've search through ArcGIS's JavaScript API docs and can't find anything that addresses this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that there will be only 12 records and that are not going to be changed...
Follow below steps to do this:

1. Add Unique value renderer instead of simple renderer.
2. Add objectID/FID as a Unique value renderer field.
3. Set this new renderer to the feature layer object.
4. Add this layer to map.

Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Sample: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=renderer_unique_value

Note: if you need exact working solution please share your layer rest URL.

Hope this will help you :)